# R package installation error (on Fedora 20)

Tags: linux, r, gcc, fedora20

I am trying to install the tm package in R but this depends on a package slam which I am having trouble installing. The error attached below cannot find -lRblas. What do I need to install on my distro so that I get this library?

Error Message

```html
    install.packages("slam")
    Installing package into ‘/home/eroche/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/slam_0.1-32.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 46672 bytes (45 Kb)
    opened URL
    ==================================================
    downloaded 45 Kb

    * installing *source* package ‘slam’ ...
    ** package ‘slam’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** libs
    gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g  -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic  -c apply.c -o apply.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic  -c grouped.c -o grouped.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic  -c sparse.c -o sparse.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic  -c util.c -o util.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o slam.so apply.o grouped.o sparse.o util.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [slam.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘slam’
* removing ‘/home/eroche/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.1/slam’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘slam’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpGsb0e4/downloaded_packages’


> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_IE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_IE.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_IE.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_IE.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_IE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: This might help https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2008-July/050094.html

Comment: I dont know a lot about linking files when compiling in c but I was hoping that I could just install a program with the correct library and that I would then be able to install as normal. Is this possible?

Comment: Your command fails with 'Rblas' not found, and Rblas is built by R when is built. One possibility could be that you just installed the rpm files to *run* R but not to also build against it -- check the pertinent FAQs for R on FC/RH.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I uninstalled R using "yum remove ^R*" and then reinstalled R and this seemed to solve my problem. Something must have gone wrong when I was updating from R 3.0 to R 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install BLAS math libraries with following command.

```
yum install blas-devel
```

Then you should try to reinstall slam.

Comment: Rblas is a version of Blas local to the R package. I think OP may now have all pieces installed.